# SELECT command wont find column name with a colon

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I have a python script to retrieve a value (table ID) from a PostgreSQL database. The column name contains a colon though and I believe this is stopping it working. I've tested this on columns without colons and it does get the ID correctly.

The line in question is

```
cur.execute("SELECT tID from titles where name like 'METEOROLOG:WINDSPEED_F' order by structure, comp1, comp2")
rowswind=cur.fetchall()
```

When I print rowswind nothing is returned (just empty brackets)

I have also tried..

```
cur.execute('SELECT tID from titles where name like "METEOROLOGY:WINDSPEED_F" order by structure, comp1, comp2')
```

But that comes back with the error

> psycopg2.ProgrammingError: column "METEOROLOGY:WINDSPEED_F" does not
>   exist

(it definitely does).

I've also tried escaping the colon any way I can think of (i.e. back slash) but nothing works, I just get syntax errors.

Any advice would be welcome. Thanks.

ADDITION 20190429

I've now tried parameterizing the query but also with no success.

```
wind=('METEOROLOGY:WINDSPEED_F')
sql="SELECT tID from titles where name like '{0}' order by structure, comp1, comp2".format(wind)
```

I've tried many different combinations of double and single quotes to try and escape the colon with no success.

Comment: It should be noted here, that your column name appears to be 'name'. That is the name of the column. These quoted values you're passing in are just values that the column name would/could equal. If you really want to get into the benefits of using `LIKE` instead of `=`, consider using `%` on either sides of the LIKE value.

Comment: Thank you, yes it did get confusing - this column 'name' contains a list of other column titles/names (namely windspeed). I did try % with LIKE but that wasn't the issue in this case.

Comment: Also, your query that works, but doesn't return results, it has METEOROLOGY spelled wrong, missing a Y....so.....

Comment: @holpot So to clarify, it's NOT the column name that contains the colon (what you use the text values for is irrelevant), it's just a simple text field? If so, can you post the EXACT value that is not being picked up in your query?

Answer (score 0):

> psycopg2.ProgrammingError: column "METEOROLOGY:WINDSPEED_F" does not exist

You're getting this error because you're using double quotes around the targeted value in your query's `WHERE` statement, here:

```
cur.execute('SELECT tID from titles where name like "METEOROLOGY:WINDSPEED_F" order by structure, comp1, comp2')
```

You're getting 0 results back here:

```
cur.execute("SELECT tID from titles where name like 'METEOROLOG:WINDSPEED_F' order by structure, comp1, comp2")
```

because 0 rows exist with the value "METEOROLOG:WINDSPEED_F" in the `name` column. **This might just be because you're spelling METEOROLOGY wrong.**

The way you're using `LIKE`, you might as well be using `=`. `LIKE` is great if you're going to use `%` to find other values *like* that value.

Example:

```
SELECT * 
FROM
    TABLE 
WHERE
    UPPER(NAME) LIKE 'JOSH%'
```

This would return results for these values in `name`: JOSHUA, JoShUa, joshua, josh, JOSH. If I straight up did `NAME LIKE 'JOSH'` then I would only find results for the exact value of `JOSH`.

Since you are making the value all caps in your `WHERE`, try this adding an `UPPER()` to your query like this:

```
cur.execute("SELECT tID from titles where UPPER(name) like 'METEOROLOG:WINDSPEED_F' order by structure, comp1, comp2")
```

Comment: Not sure if `UPPER(column) LIKE value` is more efficient than `column ILIKE value`. In any case it's an alternative.

Comment: @404, I believe `UPPER()`/`LOWER()` is quicker than `ILIKE`

Comment: Apologies, METEROROLOG was a typo on this page only - its fine in the script. The LIKE, %, UPPER etc options dont seem to get around the colon problem.

Comment: @holpot Can you tell me if you get results when you implement this: `like 'METEOROLOGY%'` ? What if you add the colon before the `%`, do you get results then?